# Archiving Postgres table data older then 60 days to s3 and deleting from table

Tags: postgresql

I have got a postgresql table on AWS RDS. Our table has grown in size and we now want to implement DR on the table. We want to push data older than 60 days to S3 bucket and delete this data from the table.

I have ruled out

1. AWS data pipeline, pg_dump as it takes the dump of whole database/table.
2. Ruled out partitioning as it means more space on AWS [ means more money for hosting]

I am thinking to use copy command from psql with select to fetch data in to file and upload something like:

```
psql -hmyhostname.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com —dmydatabasename -UmyUserName -c "copy(SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.”createdAT” < NOW() - INTERVAL ’60 days' LIMIT 1) to stdout" > /tmp/Oldder_data_than_60days.sql
```

There could be another way to implement this by duplicating the table, deleting the new data and then taking pg_dump.

I am not sure what approach should I use or if there is a better approach?

Also, once the upload to s3 is done, what would be the best way to do the delete of these million records effectively without causing performance issues on production table.